# Problem updating LINQ results with anonymous type...read only?

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-3.5

**Hello,**

I'm learning LINQ and have run into a problem.  I created a simple query against the northwind db, and I'm shaping the fields that should be returned.  The problem is After run , I can't modify any of the fields in my AspxGridView .

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="CategoryID">
    <Columns>
        <dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
            <EditButton Visible="True">
            </EditButton>
            <NewButton Visible="True">
            </NewButton>
            <DeleteButton Visible="True">
            </DeleteButton>
        </dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="CategoryID" FieldName="CategoryID" 
            VisibleIndex="1">
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="CategoryName" FieldName="CategoryName" 
            VisibleIndex="2">
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Description" FieldName="Description" 
            VisibleIndex="3">
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
</dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

**C# syntax:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
    var r = db.Categories
        .Select(p=>new {p.CategoryID,p.CategoryName,p.Description});
    ASPxGridView1.DataSource = r;
    ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

You guys may say it's problem for **var** anonymous type .But i always need to use anonymous type.How to solve this problem

Comment: You can't modify the fields how? What code are you using to try to modify the fields? What error are you getting?

Comment: In the sample you provided, I see the `var r` assignment, but where is `lresult` being created/populated? Also, I don't understand what you mean by "I always need to use anonymous type". You should be able to use anything that supports `IEnumerable` for your datasource. Additionally, having that code naked in the `Page_Load` without a check for `IsPostback` could be a likely problem, as the grid's data would be rebuilt and rebound on each postback, making editing nigh impossible.

Comment: sorry for lresult.after use this i can not modify my fields.why not u test your self

Comment: OK, are you trying to update the dataset you have just within the page, or are you trying to push those changes back to the database? i must say, updating the data itself will be difficult, as you are using an anonymous projection, which isn't going to lend itself to updating. Can you include the code you are trying to use to update? I see in the template that you have an Update button, but I don't see that CommandNames are set. A traditional ASP.NET DataGrid control works this way and I imagine the DevExpress controls have a similar feature. Maybe OnRowUpdated ?

Comment: plz try to understand my problem.I dont need help to update or insert on backend.To understand my problem plz run the code go on insert or edit mode than you can not insert any value of fields.I want to know why?

Answer (score 5):

Don't think it is possible.

Anonymous types are class types that consist of one or more public **read-only** properties.

Quoted from [http://msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Comment: i know that.But i want to know is there any solution to solve this problem.Suppose there are  two table"Orders"and "OrdersDetail"of Northwind database.Now i need to select both tabil values than what to do .is list type declaration work on .Than how to .Plz send some syntax

Comment: If you don't want them to be readonly then you CAN NOT use ANONYMOUS TYPES, but instead you have to define your own classes.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

Scott Guthrie covered it in [part 9 of his LINQ to SQL series](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx):

> One feature that *will not* work with custom shapes/projections, though, is inline editing support.  This is because we are doing a custom projection in our Selecting event, and so the LinqDataSource has no way to safely know how to update an underlying entity object.  If we want to add editing support to the GridView with a custom shaped type, we'd want to either move to using an ObjectDataSource control (where we could supply a custom Update method method to handle the updates), or have the user navigate to a new page when performing updates - and display a DetailsView or FormView control that was bound to a Product entity for editing (and not try and do inline editing with the grid).

Comment: i dont want to use datasource.I want to fill grid back end on C#.Than what to do .your given url describe how to work gridview using DataSource.Will u plz help me to fill grid by using C#